# Run bash script on every git commit

Tags: git, bash

Out of curiosity, I would like to benchmark a project I have been working on for a while, to see how it's performance at various tasks has varied over time.  This project is stored in a git repository.

Fundamentally, it seems like the correct method is

```
for r in $(git log --pretty="format:%H"); do
    git checkout $r
    echo "$r\t$(./benchmark.sh)" >> results.txt
done
```

This seems like a hack however (using porcelain for a plumbing task, for starters), and so I am wondering if there is a "preferred" method for this, such as (I wish)

```
git black_magic-run-on-all ./benchmark.sh > results.txt
```

It seems like a common enough task, which is why I expect something to exist for this.

Comment: See git hooks (man githooks) -> https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html - Using these you can run scripts at various places in the SCM logic

Comment: Quite interesting, but not what I'm looking for in this case.  This is a "I have two years of history, and I want to make a graph out of it" issue.  I don't have a need to do this synchronously.

Comment: `git bisect run` might be something similar, but meant for another situation.

Comment: Ohhh, apologies @zebediah49 maybe you'll find a use for git hooks some other day ;-)

Comment: @Ron-Dahlgren Oh, totally agree.. even the obvious "make sure it compiles without error" test is a wonderful option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for starters you can use
[`rev-list`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html)

```
git rev-list HEAD
```